# Using Point Cloud Library in Python

Tags: c++, python, point-cloud-library

Hello I am trying to use Point Cloud Library in Python and as I am new to this C++ library and Python I am following the tutorial on http://strawlab.github.io/python-pcl/#pcl.PointCloud

However whenever I try to import pcl and define a module such as `pcl.PointCloud()` I get the following error;

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PointCloud'
```

I have used `sys.path.append` to point to the correct directory where the PCL files have been installed as they are not in site packages. It says on the above link that the C++ code has already got Python bindings but I am unsure exactly what files I am trying to call in Python. Does anybody know how to overcome this error and load these modules?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: How do you import pcl in Python? Show us the code.

Comment: Can you please show how do you import pcl?

Comment: I followed the example in the tutorial which the link is above, using the code `import pcl` then tried to called the PointCloud module using `pcl.PointCloud()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sweptlaser/python3-pcl
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pcl
```

After you've done that then you should be able to run:

```
python3 -c 'import pcl'
```

and it will return with no error (as opposed to `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pcl'`).

**Tested on:**

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Python 3.6.9

Reference: https://askubuntu.com/a/1170661/922137

Answer (score 0):

Try skipping the parentheses:

```
from pcl import PointCloud
```

And then create an instance of PointCloud, for example, `p`:

```
p = PointCloud()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the response but this didn't seem to solve the problem. This time the error said `ImportError: cannot import name PointCloud`

Comment: I think i misunderstood your question, hang on.

Comment: Can you tell me how do you install `pcl`?

Comment: I installed `pcl` from the following website http://pointclouds.org/downloads/windows.html and installed the 1.6.0 All-in-one installer. A college then said I should be able to follow the tutorial and load the `pcl` library into python without having to use the likes of `ctypes` or `cython` because it already had python bindings

Comment: And how exactly do you import it?

Comment: I was using `import sys``sys.path.append('directory')``import pcl` and this seems to work without any problems but then went I try and call a directory such as `pcl.PointCloud()` I get the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need PCL 1.5.1 and cython 0.16 according to this page: http://strawlab.github.io/python-pcl/

Comment: That is out-of-sync with the code; you can look in setup.py to see what versions of pcl are accepted at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

"""https://blog.pollithy.com/python/numpy/pointcloud/tutorial-pypcd"""

python3.6 -m pip install --user git+https://github.com/DanielPollithy/pypcd.git

Comment: this is a sure fix

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.